# realloc function that would work for memory allocated using new instead of realloc

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm aware that there is a [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) function that would allow me to resize the memory block (and it's paired with a free function). However, I'm trying to do the same to a c++ class with some member pointers allocated memory using **new** instead of **realloc**. Is there an equivalent keyword to **realloc** in c++ that would allow me to achieve the same goal when the memory is paired using new/delete rather than malloc or realloc and free?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. And frankly, if you are using new or new[]. your C++ code is probably not well designed. Look at using **std::vector** instead of new[], and at using values instead of new.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using an ordinary "new" in C++ code, although it should probably be used in conjuction with boost::shared_ptr or one of the other BOOST smart pointer classes.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it if you know what you are doing. But using values should be the first choice.

Comment: Sometimes values aren't a viable option (e.g. a C++ object which is shared between multiple objects).

Comment: well use a vector of shared_ptr :)

Comment: vectors of shared_ptr have additional refcount overhead. That's not a good solution. boost:ptr_vector would be an alternative though.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of if there is one or not, but you could probably use a vector as you are just resizing an array of elements :)

```
std::vector<char> iVector(1000); // 1000 element as initial size

iVector.resize(2500); // resize the vector to 2500 elements

// or just use it without worrying about memory management
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, you have a class which allocate some variable-length memory. There is two possible cases:

#### The memory contains C++ objects

You have no choice: The memory should be, directly or indirectly allocated with new because you need the constructors called.

If you want to have a realloc-like behaviour, then do not use new[]. Use instead a std::vector, which will handle all the allocation/reallocation/Free and construction/destruction correctly.

#### The memory is raw

You could either use new[] or malloc, because you are allocating PODs (an array of ints, or shorts, dumb structures, etc.).

But again, new[] won't offer you a realloc-like behaviour... But if you start using malloc, then you must do housekeeping, i.e. be sure to call free at the right time, memorize the size of the array somewhere, and perhaps even have a size different from the array capacity (i.e. you allocate more, to avoid doing too much reallocs).

And you know what? std::vector already do all this for you.

#### Conclusion

You are coding in C++, then the solution to your problem (i.e. allocating variable length memory inside a class), as already expressed by previous answers, is **use std::vector**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how vector uses placement new to initialize, copy (move) and destruct objects in-place in memory that is in principle 'realloc'-ated. There is a fair amount of work in implementing something like vector, so I'd say simply use vector... It uses one contiguous memory block for all the objects, so you can use it with functions that expect arrays. And, it implicitly keeps track of the count of objects for you...

Of course, this convenience comes with a cost - it allocates memory on the heap behind the scenes.
So if you absolutely know that you only need a reasonably sized array then an array on the stack can not be beaten for speed.

BR
Per

Answer (score -3):

No. Just use malloc/realloc/free, what's problem?

Comment: The problem with malloc/realloc/free in C++ is that they are not guaranteed to invoke constructors and destructors correctly, whereas using the new and delete keywords guarantee correct construction/destruction.

Comment: Not are they not guaranteed to call ctors & dtors, they won't call them.