# Regrow memory allocated by operator new()?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to regrow memory allocated by `operator new()`, when allocated this way:

```
char* buf = new char[60];
```

The [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.5) states that memory allocated by `new` cannot be resized by realloc, so what's the correct way to regrow memory allocated by `new`?

Comment: There isn't an analogous operation to `realloc` with the C++ `new`/`delete` system (by default). If you need to use `new`, you probably really want an `std::vector`. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179669/realloc-function-that-would-work-for-memory-allocated-using-new-instead-of-reallo

Comment: Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179669/realloc-function-that-would-work-for-memory-allocated-using-new-instead-of-reallo) there isn't one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to use `std::vector` or `std::string` depending on your particular usage of the array--let C++ handle allocation for you.

If you *must* use `new`, you'll have to reallocate and copy the memory. This simple templated function shows you the basics:

```
template <typename T>
T *GrowArray(T *oldArray, size_t oldCount, size_t newCount) {
    T *newArray = new T[newCount];
    if (oldArray) {
        std::copy(oldArray, oldArray + std::min(oldCount, newCount), newArray);
        delete[] oldArray;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Note that, in most implementations and with most use cases, this is essentially what `realloc()` does, minus the type safety. If this looks inefficient to you, well, `realloc()` probably isn't doing anything better.

Comment: +1 for correct solution with correct (at a glance) code, but calling this method `GrowArray` is a bit misleading.  The original pointers are no good after the call.

Comment: @John - nothing proper documentation can't handle. :)

Comment: Your comment about `realloc` isn't really correct.  While `realloc` *might* do something similar to the function you posted, it's just as likely to use OS-specific knowledge to "extend" the array without copying the contents of the array.  For example, on some Linux versions, a memory block returned by `malloc` is prepended with a size variable that is inaccessible to the programmer, but accessible to the internal implementation.  When `realloc` is called, the implementation can check this variable to see if it's possible to extend the array without copying everything.

Comment: @Charles: I know--I was simplifying. For calls where the size increases by a small amount/does not cross a page boundary, yes, the OS will be able to optimize and not reallocate. However, for larger resizes, my comments stand.

Comment: @John: The original pointer to `realloc` is no good after a successful call either.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way is to not do it.

Simply allocate new memory if the previous allocation wasn't big enough.

Or use `std::vector` which wraps all this functionality very efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::vector`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html)

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to do a second new, copy the content and then delete the old memory block:

```
char *tmpbuff = new char[70];
memcpy(tmpbuff, buff, 60 * sizeof(char));
delete [] buff;
buff = tmpbuff;
```

(No...C++ is not equal to STL, so there is a life without STL :-) )