# Reallocating an array that is an instance member

Tags: c++

This is a follow up to [this answer (which talks about regrowing a general array, not an array that is an instance variable, in particular)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737261):

I have to use the c-style array.

In the below example, I mean for `oldArray` to contain T's.

```
T *newArray = new T[newCount];
if (oldArray) {
    std::copy(oldArray, oldArray + std::min(oldCount, newCount), newArray);
    delete[] oldArray;
}
```

Suppose oldArray is an instance variable and I want to regrow it. This code gives me the pointer to the newly grown array but if I delete oldArray, I can't use it any more :(

Comment: just use a `std::vector`. it handles all the memory management for you automatically.

Comment: I *have* to use the c-style array

Comment: "Everything can be solved with an extra layer of indirection (except a problem of too many layers)" - you can have your instance variable **point** to an array. That way you can change your pointer to whatever memory you consider being your current array

Comment: @YePhIcK that is exactly what `std::vector` achieves

Comment: OP mentioned that the use of c-style arrays is a-must

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn: Is `oldArray` a pointer to `T` or an actual array of `T`? If it's a pointer then `oldArray = newArray`, if it's an array then you can't reallocate it. I hope your class does the right thing for copying, assignment, and destruction.

Comment: Please elaborate, with some code preferably, what you mean by `Suppose oldArray is an instance variable and I want to regrow it.`

Comment: @YePhIcK he didn't mention it to me. Also, you can be sure that `std::vector` uses c-style arrays :)

Comment: OP mentioned that in a comment (above). But yeah, I do know that `std::vector` uses c-style arrays internally. :)

Comment: `oldArray = newArray;`

Comment: @YePhIcK: That's complete nonsense. `std::vector` uses an allocator and separates memory allocation from object construction. And the OP's code doesn't even have a "C-style array", since C has no dynamic array objects.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn: I don't think it's helpful to mix C into the discussion. C has a very different object model from C++, and in particular it doesn't have dynamic arrays (i.e. arrays with manually managed lifetime). The C++ construction `new T[N]` constructs objects, which includes code execution; there's no analogue of that in C, nor is that something you generally want, ever. `std::vector` shows a much more useful approach to dynamic container design, namely separating object lifetimes from memory allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could use the function in the reference as is.

```
oldArray = GrowArray(oldArray, oldCount, newCount);
```

It could be modified to use a local temporary and then `std::swap`, but this would depend a lot on the context in which it is used.

Comment: This requires a lot less refactoring than if I have to change oldArray from a pointer to T to a pointer to a pointer of T. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean you can't use NAME oldArr in your next code. If I right understand you, I offering you next solve. You need create regrow function ("realloc" in my code), then in your main code you need reassign pointer.

```
class T {
public:
    int x;
};

T* realloc( T* oldArray, int oldCount, int newCount ){
    T *newArray = new T[newCount];
    if (oldArray) {
        std::copy(oldArray, oldArray + std::min(oldCount, newCount), newArray);
        delete[] oldArray;
    }

    return newArray;
}

void main()
{
    int arr_size = 2;
    T* arr = new T[ arr_size ];

    arr[0].x = 10;
    arr[1].x = 20;
    std::cout<<"arr[0]="<<arr[0].x<<", arr[1]="<<arr[1].x<<"\n";

    int arr_new_size = 3;
    arr = realloc( arr, arr_size, arr_new_size );

    arr[2].x = 30;
    std::cout<<"arr[0]="<<arr[0].x<<", arr[1]="<<arr[1].x<<", arr[2]="<<arr[2].x;
}
```